# Redundancy in "jetzt sofort"

Tags: redundancy

I have heard in the [ZDF news](https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten-sendungen/heute-journal/heute-journal-vom-19-maerz-2024-100.html#showSubtitles=true) (0:40 minutes) :

> 10000 Schuss aus Bundeswehrbeständen soll die Ukraine jetzt sofort bekommen.

Isn't "jetzt" redundant, given that "sofort" is already used? In English and Romance languages, the words equivalent to them would never be used together. For instance, a usual way to say the sentence in English would be:

Ukraine is to receive 10,000 rounds from German armed forces stocks immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Jetzt sofort* in this quote is probably just a redundant idiom so express "really immediately. However, there is also some nuance to usage of *jetzt* in oral language.

The *jetzt* could refer to the whole utterance, and thus describe that the decision has happened "now".  *Sofort* then refers to the time that the action is to be taken -- the immediate delivery of ammunition. (I believe that this is what Janka wants to express with their translation of *jetzt* as "nowadays".)

In this sense, *jetzt* functions a bit like a sentence adverbial (or even modal particle?) to highlight the recency of the conveyed information ("what I say is new content"), whereas *sofort* is merely a temporal adverb describing the time of the action.

In examples:

> Vor einem Monat wurde beschlossen, dass die Ukraine sofort Munition bekommen sollte.

The decision was made in the past, but delivery was to happen immediately.

> Die Ukraine soll Munition jetzt [doch] erst in einem Monat bekommen.

The decision was made now and is considered news (or even a surprise, i.e., against what was expected by the speaker, which can be highlighted by the particle *doch*); the delivery is to happen in the future.

> Die Ukraine soll jetzt sofort Munition bekommen.

The decision was made now to immediately deliver.

> Vor einem Monat wurde beschlossen, dass die Ukraine jetzt Munition bekommen sollte.

The (unexptected) decision was made in the past.  Delivery time is unspecified.

> Die Ukraine soll jetzt nächste Woche Munition bekommen.

The decision was made now about delivery in the future.

**Note:** Using *jetzt* in this way is mostly a feature of oral language. The examples are gradually less acceptable in written style. I would never use the last one in a written text, but definitely say something similar in an informal conversation.

Comment: If it's oral only, I would bet that it's a modal particle.

Comment: In the sense mentioned here, _jetzt_ could be replaced by _nun_

Answer (score 9):

> ... soll die Ukraine jetzt bekommen.

means, it's agreed upon and now we can work on the realization. But that could take another five month until it's finally there. The *jetzt* refers back to *soll*.

> ... soll die Ukraine jetzt **sofort** bekommen.

means, it will be sent there immediately.

Comment: I disagree.  *»Sebastian soll jetzt das Geld bekommen.«* does not mean, that someone decided now, that he shall get the money sometimes (maybe in five month). It means *"Sebastian is now to receive the money."* And so *»Die Ukraine soll  jetzt 10.000 Schuss Munition bekommen.«* means *»Ukraine is now to receive 10,000 rounds of ammunition.«* It does not mean *»Someone has now decided that Ukraine should receive 10,000 rounds of ammunition at some point (perhaps in five months).«*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I disagree. *"Sebastian is now to receive the money."* would be *"Sebastian erhält jetzt ... "* not *"Sebastian soll jetzt ... erhalten"*.

Comment: I guess  both of you have a point, but neither view is unconditionally correct. *Sebastian bekommt jetzt das Geld* may mean, that he is right now receiving the money, or that the earlier decision was, that he receives no money, but **now** that decision was changed. I consider the reference point for *jetzt* as ambiguous and either emphasis in speech or more context are needed for resolving the ambiguity.

Comment: The emphasis in speech is in "sofort", as you can see in the link to the video in my question. I agree the meaning is ambiguous and the meaning in this answer would be much clearer if the speaker explicitly said: "Es wurde jetzt beschlossen, dass die Ukraine sofort 10000 Schuss Munition..."

Comment: @AlanEvangelista The guy is reporting a decision that he was not involved in. He's also not involved in the actions to take place based on that decision. Hence the *soll*. The *jetzt* is the time of report. The reported fact is true right now and in the future: the decision. *Sofort* is the reportrd time of actions.

Comment: It kinda means that ("agreed upon"), but the more pressing issue in the news-cycle is that Ukraine would in the worst case scenario cease to exist in the not so distant future in which case the deal is off. It's a simple two sided equation (U needs help new. We can act now and we will ((c) Scholz, probably)). The grammar concerns left and right peripheri, I guess. The problem is that the paramters and arguments are distributed so immediately close so as to appear not just redundant but self-similar.

Answer (score 0):

*Jetzt* is a tricky word that can mean *now* but often enough, it doesn't. Its real meaning is closer to *nowadays*.

> … soll die Ukraine **jetzt** sofort bekommen.

*… should Ukraine receive immediately **nowadays.***

That *jetzt* is meant in opposition to times when this decision was unthinkable.

Comment: "should Ukraine receive immediately nowadays" does not make sense in English. I think the meaning you mentioned would be reworded to something like "It was decided today that Ukraine should immediately receive..."

Comment: But that's not what *jetzt* means. It means 
*in contrast to before*.

Comment: I don't follow. Before what? The news are reporting something that happened very recently, but for sure it happened before the time the news were recorded and broadcasted (therefore not **now**). Maybe German uses "jetzt" for things that happened in a recent past? English does not. Or are you saying "jetzt" implies a change in how the issue was handled by Germany? If so, I don't see how that's different from "it was decided today/recently", which also imply the same change, but it's less ambiguous and less confusing than putting "jetzt" and "sofort" next to each other in the same sentence.

Comment: *Jetzt* is used to indicate that something changed. E.g. *Kannst du jetzt kommen?* more often than not does **not** ask if someone has time to come *now* but instead it asks if the obstacles that prevented coming have been removed. The actual action of „coming“ may happen later. — I think this is one of those tricky modal particle uses.

Answer (score 0):

Is it redundant? - Yes.
Is it wrong? - No.
Is it bad style? - No. (Sometimes it is, but not here.)
Is it usual? - Yes.

Redundancy is a frequently used stylistic device.

> Der große Bär kam auf mich zu.
> Der riesige Bär kam auf mich zu.
> Der riesige große Bär kam auf mich zu.

The adjective *groß* means *big* and *riesig* means *huge.* So the last sentence is

> The huge big bear came towards me.

These two adjectives with very similar meaning are used together to emphasize the meaning of both of them.
<sub>(In case of adjectives you often use one of them not as attribute, but adverbial (*»der riesig große Bär ...«*) and sometimes you even can combine them to one word (*»der riesengroße Bär ...«*), but that is specific to adjectives and beyond the scope of this answer.)</sub>

The term, linguists use to name this style, is [plenonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) which means *"abundance", "exaggeration"* or *"excess".*

A pleonasm is often considered bad style, because it provides information, that is already there

- eine runde Kugel (a round ball; but balls are always round, so there is no need to say it)
- das kalte Eis (the cold ice; but ice is always cold)

But you in some cases, the redundancy works as a mutual amplification, and this is the case with *jetzt sofort*

> 1. Mach das jetzt!
> 2. Mach das sofort!
> 3. Mach das jetzt sofort!

All three sentences mean *»Do it now!«* But the version #3 is much more urgent and stronger than #1 or #2.

Comment: The answer would be correct as a general answer on the use of _jetzt sofort_, but in the specific context of the question, the sentence is equivalent to _Jetzt soll die Ukraine 1000 Schuss [...] sofort bekommen_, with a slightly nuanced meaning, see Janka's answer.

Comment: It can be argued that any redundancy/pleonasm could be used to give emphasis to an idea. It seems to me that they are more common/tolerable in German than in English in non-literary contexts.

Comment: I think the pleonasm is a strong element here. "Räum' Dein Zimmer auf!" "Jetzt?" "Ja, jetzt sofort!" It's "now, immediately!" Of course language is ambivalent: In the original sentence, the "jetzt" as well as the English equivalent "now" also carry the idea of a new resolution or situation: "We reconsidered; *now* (as opposed to yesterday) we plan to deliver 100k ammo" ("nach weiteren Beratungen soll die Ukraine *jetzt* 100k Munition bekommen"). We don't know what exactly was meant in which proportion, and I suspect the author didn't either. The beauty of natural language.